# Cannot change logo or colors of a scheme

Tags: theming

Hello I use Open Atrium based on Drupal. I can use the standard Radix 7.x theme, but even with that I cannot change the color scheme by saving it via Colorize. If I then use another theme I cannot even get the logo to display or any submenu to appear. I am not sure if it is a question of permissions. The site is installed on a VM as part of a webmin set up. I have seem very nice sites in both Drupal and OA so I am sure I should be able to customize my site, but it just does not work. The colorize shows the result on Radix, but as soon as I save it it forgets it. In my experience this might either mean that the path to the new colors (CSS?) is not valid, reachable or has the wrong permissions. DO you have any idea of what I can try? I need nothing fancy, but I'd like to customize the logo and colours and have all the Radix menus in another there, e.g. Bartik....Thanks in advance for any help you can give me. Please note I am not a programmer...if you advise me to change something in the code I can do it but you have to give me the full instructions. Thank you so much. regards
Enea

Answer (score 1):

I'd check the folder/file permissions set on the "public files" folder for Drupal, especially the sub-folders (css, js, color) because if those aren't set right then the Color module can't write changes for custom CSS and logo uploads.

Answer (score 0):

Check your permissions on the `sites/default/files` folder.

- The logo will be uploaded as `sites/default/files/yourlogo.png`
- The color will be uploaded as `sites/default/files/color`

You can check the permissions of this folder at `admin/reports/status`. Check the `File system` option. If it's not writable, you will see the following message:

> The directory sites/default/files is not writable.

You can adjust this setting at `admin/config/media/file-system`.